# NAnt + Project with GUID must be included

Tags: nant

I just started using NAnt today, I followed some of the examples. I am having a hard time with one issue:

Its saying: "Project with GUID '{32845370-6F32-411F-B4C5-383F9C3EDE29}' must be included for
the build to work."

Now I was able to track down the project. Here is my directory structure:

`c:\dev\stockclockbuild` -> this is where the solution and build file is located.
So I run the command:

```
nant -buildfile:c:\dev\stockclockbuild\stocks.build
```

I have a project that it located in `c:\dev\_sharedlibs\mdrlibs` called "MDR.StockPlatform" which seems to get included, but within that project file I found the project (dependency) that has the GUID mentioned in the error.

That project is called "MDR.Base" but its located in the same folder as MDR.StockPlatform.
**Also if I were to open this solution and build it in visual studio it builds without errors.**

Here is the complete verbose output:

```
c:\Dev\_Misc\Tools\nAnt\bin>nant -buildfile:c:\dev\stockclockbuild\stocks.build
NAnt 0.92 (Build 0.92.4543.0; release; 6/9/2012)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///c:/dev/stockclockbuild/stocks.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
Target(s) specified: rebuild


clean:


build:


build.stockclock:

 [solution] Starting solution build.
 [solution] Loading projects...
 [solution] Loading project 'c:\dev\stockclockbuild\StockClock.Common\StockClock
.Common.csproj'.
 [solution] Using MSBuild version 4.0.30319.1.
 [solution] Loading referenced project 'c:\dev\_SharedLibs\MDRLibs\MDR.StockPlat
form\MDR.StockPlatform.csproj'.

BUILD FAILED

Project with GUID '{32845370-6F32-411F-B4C5-383F9C3EDE29}' must be included for
the build to work.

Total time: 0.6 seconds.
```

Here is a copy of the build file:

```
<project name="Solution Build Example" default="rebuild">
    <property name="configuration" value="release"/>

    <target name="clean" description="Delete all previously compiled binaries.">
        <delete>
            <fileset>
                <include name="**/bin/**" />
                <include name="**/obj/**" />
                <include name="**/*.suo" />
                <include name="**/*.user" />
            </fileset>
        </delete>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Build all targets.">
        <call target="build.stockclock"/>
    </target>

    <target name="rebuild" depends="clean, build" />

    <target name="build.stockclock">
        <solution configuration="${configuration}" solutionfile="Stockclock.sln" verbose="true">
        </solution>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Wait, and why do you need NAnt for that? MSBuild 4.0 is perfectly capable of everything NAnt is (and quite similar in syntax, to be honest).

Comment: To be honest I started looking at NAnt because it supposedly  integrates nicely with NUnit. Although I am currently not using those features I was planning to. We already use NUnit.

Comment: There's a NUnit task in https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks MSBuildCommunity. And you can just invoke the console runner, that's what I had to do each time with NAnt anyway (never could get it's NUnit task to work).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a modern IDE, and from the [NAnt Documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/solution.html):

```
Note: Right now, only Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2002 and 2003 solutions and
projects are supported. Support for .NET Compact Framework projects is also not
available at this time.
```

In my NAnt scripts I use the [NauckIT MSBuild task](http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/utilities/wiki/NAntTasksMSBuild):

```xml
<msbuild projectFile="${solution.file}" targets="Build" verbosity="Quiet">
    <property name="Configuration" value="${build.configuration}" />
    <property name="Platform" value="${build.platform}" />
    <arg value="/flp:NoSummary;Verbosity=normal;LogFile=${build.log}" />
    <arg value="/p:SignAssembly=true" if="${isReleaseBuild}" />
    <arg value="/p:AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile=${solution.keyfile}" if="${isReleaseBuild}" />
    <arg value="/p:DelaySign=false" if="${isReleaseBuild}" />
</msbuild>
```

However that is a personal preference as you could also use the [NAnt exec task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) and call msbuild directly.